# Jenkins pipeline/groovy: Load script relative to current script

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline groovy script, which I load from a different script:

```
load("path/to/my/script/pipeline.groovy")
```

Now, in this script, I want  to load another groovy script. But I do not know the full `path/to/my/script` path. I tried:

```
load("./subfolder/subscript.groovy")
```

But it cannot find it this way. Can I somehow load a groovy script relative to the current script file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using [the shared library plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) if you are loading multiple remote scripts.

If the groovy file exists in a subfolder, you can use the [findFiles step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-findfiles-code-find-files-in-the-workspace):

```
def subscript = findFiles(glob: '**/subscript.groovy') 
load(subscript[0].path)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to load the 2nd script (curl) in your working directory, from there the 1st script can find and load it.